# Change the color of item in table of content

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, itemize, tocloft

The color of the item in the presentation was changed. But, In the table of content, I still saw old color and couldn't fine change the way of the color of the item in the table of content. I used the following setting:

```
\definecolor{subred}{HTML}{ff3333}
\definecolor{subsubred}{HTML}{ff6666}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=subred}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=subsubred}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem in toc}{fg=subred}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{660000}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{subred}{HTML}{ff3333}
\definecolor{subsubred}{HTML}{ff6666}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=subred}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=subsubred}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem in toc}{fg=subred}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{660000}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=subred}


\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]